# Why high number of closed questions? Extremely annoying.

Tags: discussion, subjective

What's the point of a subjective site when "too localized" questions or unpopular questions are asked.  You would expect to see LESS closed questions here than elsewhere.

Becoming very annoying and un-enjoyable.  Is it really THAT bad to have this board be of programming discussion with the original catalyst as the question?

Comment: Yes, it really is that bad.

Comment: I still think that not enough questions are closed for this site to be useful as anything other than a distraction.

Comment: @Eric - There are still some great questions on here but they're in the minority.

Answer (score 16):

Because this is not a "subjective site." Programmers.SE's purpose is to handle questions of interest to programmers which are not directly related to coding (Stack Overflow is about *coding*, explicitly). Those questions will *tend* to be more subjective than the topics on Stack Overflow, so we set up some guidelines for asking subjective questions which fall within the scope of good Q&A: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

If questions cannot fit within the "Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions," they need to be closed.

> What's the point of a subjective site...

Yeah, that's the crux of the issue. **There is no point** to a subjective site. "Subjective" is not a topic. You don't major in *subjective*. You cannot become an expert at *subjective*.

This [has been covered](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/is-programmers-se-a-discussion-board-or-a-qa-board/433#433) extensively. If folks really want to hang out at a site which hosts [fairly stupid water-cooler nonsense](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/), Stack Exchange simply is not the best venue. You'd be much better off setting up a phpBB forum somewhere.

Comment: Or talk about whatever you want on chat.

Comment: @Robert, for my own information, where does one major at objective? Just trying to improve your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The site is subjective regardless of what some of the posters might think. When we start having a site that caters to programmers' interests, that becomes subjective and subject to up/down voting as expressed by whoever constitute the mass of posters with the power to vote up/down.

Some questions are valid but closed because of being too localized, but then you have these inane questions that continue to exist despite logic dictating to close the damned thing. People vote up and down on a whim as if they were in Myspace (with many of the posters being just out of HS and still pretending to be the second reincarnation of Dijkstra.)

So what you have is a combination of the worst posting elements of Yahoo!Answers, MySpace and slashdot, all mixed in a cabalistic abomination, semi-moderated by whim rather than procedure.

You cannot help yourself from being annoyed, but don't let it get under your skin either. For every gold nugget of info you get here, you'll get a bucket of crap with crawling roaches on it. You have to determine if the signal-to-noise ratio makes it worthwhile the reading.

Comment: I agree. Subjective seems far too reflexive around here. Multiple objectively correct answers to a question does not make a question subjective. Likewise, sometimes there can occasionally be objective answers to questions containing the word ‘best’. Though without fail, some idiot won’t bother trying to understand a question, see ‘best’ and close the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is something to do with the site's name: **Programmers**

People think it's about coding, and when they get there, they see soft ethereal questions, about ethics, and many onstartups-like questions.

Developers and marketing responsible could either do something clever to solve it.

Comment: How about a big link to stackoverflow.com for coding questions in the banner?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yes, it's good to enforce the usefulness of the forum by cutting out dead weight, but when you see things like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344/what-music-do-you-code-to-closed) getting closed, while the [equivalent Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987/audio-while-programming) is still open...

Might that not be a sign that you're being just a tad overzealous on the Programmers board? Especially since the question in question is arguably a better fit for Programmers than SO (subjective, non-coding, programming related).

Comment: it's not open any longer. I just made sure it ceased to exist.

Comment: Man, I'd better not say anything about the programming cartoon questions.